# Xubuntu: xscreensaver crashes on lock screen

Tags: lock-screen, xscreensaver

I'm running 16.04 on a Dell Inspiron 5567.

I removed lightdm so my screen locker is xscreensaver. I did so because I was having trouble with bringing back the system after suspension with lightdm: the screensaver was static and I couldn't type in my password.

An hour ago I was doing a backup of my home folder (around 400GB) and I closed the lid; I went away for about an hour and when I opened the lid the screensaver was static and I couldn't type in my password; I had to hard reboot the machine by keeping the power button pressed. When I could log in I checked the logs Xorg.0.log and Xorg.0.log.old but there was no report of an error.

Any ideas on what this could be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This keeps happening, even if I don't close the lid. Please help.

Comment: This happened again while running xscreensaver-demo; out of nothing first the program stopped responding and after a few seconds mouse was unresponsive also, then all of Ubuntu; had to hard-reboot. Please help! I need to know what the cause is, if not a solution.